# Objective-C member variable assignment?

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter

I have an objective-c class with member variables. I am creating getters and setters for each one. Mostly for learning purposes. My setter looks like the following:

```
- (void) setSomething:(NSString *)input {
 something = input;
}
```

However, in C++ and other languages I have worked with in the past, you can reference the member variable by using the `this` pointer like `this->something = input`. In objective-c this is known as `self`.  So I was wondering if something like that is possible in objective-c? Something like this:

```
- (void) setSomething:(NSString *)input {
 [self something] = input;
}
```

But that would call the getter for `something`. So I'm not sure. So my question is:

***Is there a way I can do assignment utilizing the self pointer?***

If so, how?

Is this good practice or is it evil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it uses the same syntax as C++, with `self` in place of `this`:

```
self->something = input;
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning, however, that `self->` is not required and nobody actually writes code like that.

Comment: Actually, some of us do indeed use `self` to make clear the context, differentiating between an object member and a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're effectively using "self" implicitly when you use...

```
something = input;
```

...if there's no local "something" variable. (i.e.: There's really no need to add an explicit "self", and people generally don't.)

That said, your code sample isn't retaining the input, so it probably isn't going to do what you expect (well, not for long without crashing in the case of an NSString).

As such, if you *really* want to write your own setters (the Objective-C [property/synthesize](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) set up is a *lot* less hassle), you'll need to use something like:

```
- (void) setSomething:(NSString *)input {
    if(something != input) {
        [input retain];
        [something release];
        something = input;
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid the no-valid-object gap between releasing the old value and assigning the new (retained) value, one idiom is to autorelease the old `something`.

Comment: It's usually more appropriate to copy strings instead of retaining them.